# Very bad accuracy when training model with FastAI

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I am currently building a model to classify thousands of vehicle models of different car makers.
I read some chapters of the fastbook to get a code structure and build my model.
The problem is that I get absolutely disastrous results in terms of accuracy, I have already gone to the end of the training phase but I realise that the predictions are very bad (the metrics here is error_rate)
[image]

Here is the code i'm currently using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


#Affiche les class d'images peu fourni pour permettre de les enrichir
import os
import re

def count_files(directory, n_occurrences):
    files_count = {}
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            filename = file.split("_", 3)[0:3] # prends les 3 premières parties du nom de fichier
            filename = "_".join(filename) 
            if filename in files_count:
                files_count[filename] += 1
            else:
                files_count[filename] = 1
    filtered_files = [(file, count) for file, count in files_count.items() if count < n_occurrences]
    filtered_files.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
    print(filtered_files)
    
count_files('images/archive', 5)


# In[ ]:


#Nomme les classes pour le datablock
import re

def get_name(string):
  matches = re.findall(r"_", string)
  if len(matches) >= 3:
    index = string.index("_", string.index("_", string.index("_")+1)+1)
    return string[:index]
  return string


# In[ ]:


from fastai.vision.all import *


cars = DataBlock(blocks = (ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
                 get_items=get_image_files, 
                 splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.3, seed=44),
                 get_y=using_attr(get_name, 'name'),
                 item_tfms=Resize(128),
                 batch_tfms=aug_transforms(size=128))


# In[ ]:


dls = cars.dataloaders('images/archive', bs=16)


# In[ ]:


dls.show_batch(nrows=3, ncols=3)


# In[ ]:


model = xresnet34(n_out=dls.c)
learn = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=LabelSmoothingCrossEntropy(), metrics=accuracy)
learn.fine_tune(3)


# In[ ]:


#width 600
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)

#Matrice de confusion
#interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(12,12), dpi=60)

interp.most_confused(min_val=50)


# In[ ]:


lr_min,lr_steep = learn.lr_find(suggest_funcs=(minimum, steep))

print(f"Minimum/10: {lr_min:.2e}, steepest point: {lr_steep:.2e}")


# In[ ]:


#MinimumLR/10
learn.fit_one_cycle(3, 1e-8)


# In[ ]:


learn.unfreeze()


# In[ ]:


learn.lr_find()


# In[ ]:


#Lr_find[0]
learn.fit_one_cycle(6, lr_max=6e-5)


# In[ ]:


learn.fit_one_cycle(3, 6e-5)
learn.unfreeze()
learn.fit_one_cycle(12, lr_max=slice(1e-6,1e-4))


# In[ ]:

learn.recorder.plot_loss()

# In[ ]:

learn.predict('test/porsche.jpg')

# In[ ]:
```

I would really appreciate any insights and help!

Comment: Can *you* tell the car brands apart on 128x128 images?

Comment: @Lodinn 128x128 size choice is only for computational speed reason, I also tried with 224x224 but didn't get much better results unfortunalty

Comment: What are the original image sizes? Also, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28158/338509 - both are old, but main points still hold. It is hard to know how your model *should* perform, and, likely, has little to do with the software implementation. If your code works for MNIST, but not the problem you're actually interested in, the issue lies with the model or the way you prepare data. E.g. messed up labels make it almost impossible to learn.

Comment: By the looks of it, loss converges reasonably well (I'd maybe even up the lr a little bit), but the problem you are giving to the net may be hopeless: e.g. there's only a handful of images of any given car (thousands of images are not that much if there are many labels, you might need millions), and there's simply not enough to learn from. Or, rather, the only way NN would improve is by memorizing the exact dataset you are feeding to it.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try RandomForestClassifier?

First you define x and y

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn import metrics


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
```

Then you try accuracy:

```
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
accuracy
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, can you provide me more informations about how it will work better ? It will help me to select better algorithms next time

Comment: sure RF on images, very reliable....